# azure basic HTTP trigger NodeJS async

Tags: node.js, function, azure

Why is this not sending me back any data. Im using postman and its not sending any results. Some type of async issue? Maybe I didn't configure this Azure HTTP trigger functions.json config correctly?

When I pass in a local object for the response it is fine. Only when I attempt to use async its failing. I'm currently testing on my local dev machine before I deploy the function to Azure cloud.

**functions.json**

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

**index.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(response=>{
        console.log(response.data) // This is coming thru fine.
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: response.data
        }
        context.done();
    }).catch(error=>{
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: error
        }
        context.done();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly believe that the code I had before works but the more condensed version I provided below seem to do the job however if anyone runs into this issue you may want to try to restart the local development server and it may resolve the issue for you

SOLVED

```
const axios = require(‘axios’);

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    let d = await axios.get(‘https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1’);
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: d.data
    }
    context.done()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of how this solved the problem so that it will be more useful to people who might visit this question in the future?